# Возвращение элементов массива JSON. Не могу обратиться к отдельным элементам

Tags: php, javascript, json, angularjs

Суть текущей задачи такова: информацию из текстового файла "base.txt" прочитать php-обработчиком и послать в контроллер, а затем каким-то образом преобразовать в массив, чтобы можно было по ключам забивать значения в модели angular. Проще говоря, получить массив **такого вида**:

```
      $scope.notes = [
            {id:1, aDate:'12.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Cleaning" },
            {id:2, aDate:'13.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"My secret mission" },
            {id:3, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Go to the pub" },
            {id:4, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Rock'n'roll party" },
            {id:5, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Swimming pool" },
            {id:6, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Garbage day" },
        ];
```

Для этого я создал php-файл:

```
        <?php
                $ifLoad = $_POST['data'];

                $f = fopen("base.txt", "rt");

                $file_array = file("base.txt");
                // Закрыть текстовый файл
                echo json_encode($file_array);
                fclose($f);
        ?>
```

Его принимает функция в контроллере:

```
    $scope.init = function () {
              alert("onload"); 
              $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "loadBase.php",
                                data: "load",
                                success: function(responseText){
                                  $myArray=responseText;
                                   $myArray=JSON.parse(responseText);
                                   alert($myArray)
                                   $('.resultsHandler').html($myArray);
                                  },   
                                error:  function(xhr, str){
                                        alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                                }
                              });       
    };
```

А вот результат, который я получаю преобразовав json:

```
[{"id":1,"aDate":"12.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Cleaning","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":2,"aDate":"13.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"My secret mission","$$hashKey":"object:4"},{"id":3,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Go to the pub","$$hashKey":"object:5"},{"id":4,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Rock'n'roll party","$$hashKey":"object:6"},{"id":5,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Swimming pool","$$hashKey":"object:7"},{"id":6,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Garbage day","$$hashKey":"object:8"}]
```

Не совсем то, что мне нужно, плюс я так и не понял как обращаться к конкретным элементам массива и их полям. Прошу помощи, в документации очень слабо расписан метод JSON.parse(text [, reviver]).

Comment: `$myArray[0].id`, `$myArray[1].id`

Comment: пробовал. Возвращает "undefined"( В том-то и суть, вроде должно по логике было работать(

Comment: Что вам выводит вот этот `alert($myArray)` сейчас? Только `;` поставьте после него. И именно на том коде который вы отобразили в вопросе, а не на другом.

Comment: [{"id":1,"aDate":"12.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Cleaning","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":2,"aDate":"13.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"My secret mission","$$hashKey":"object:4"},{"id":3,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Go to the pub","$$hashKey":"object:5"},{"id":4,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Rock'n'roll party","$$hashKey":"object:6"},{"id":5,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Swimming pool","$$hashKey":"object:7"},{"id":6,"aDate":"14.08.15","aTime":"12.00","aNote":"Garbage day","$$hashKey":"object:8"}]

Comment: а надо:$scope.notes = [
            {id:1, aDate:'12.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Cleaning" },
            {id:2, aDate:'13.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"My secret mission" },
            {id:3, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Go to the pub" },
            {id:4, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Rock'n'roll party" },
            {id:5, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Swimming pool" },
            {id:6, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Garbage day" },
        ];

Comment: @Сергей, `$scope.notes = JSON.parse(responseText);` не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно, не увидел существенной разницы между объектами, которые вы оставили в комментариях.

`$$hashKey` - это свойство, которое использует ангуляр для своих внутренних нужд, вас оно не должно интересовать вообще. Если вы сохраняете подобные данные в файл на сервере, то можете обрабатывать полученный объект перед сохранением, удаляя все подобные поля `$$xxx` в объектах.

Записи `{"foo": "bar"}` и `{foo: "bar"}` полностью эквивалентны в JS.

В ангуляре есть свой удобный API для ajax-запросов, используйте сервис [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Обычно подобный функционал (обращение к серверу) выносят в отдельный сервис.